# You're all caught up!

Tags: meaning

What does the term "You're all caught up!" means, many a time I see this on my WordPress account & also on Google Plus.

Comment: It means you're no longer behind on your work.

Comment: Or you've heard all the latest gossip or you've paid all your bills.  Impossible to say without context.

Comment: It means your bridal train is caught in the church door.  (Highly context dependent.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that what you know, what you've read, or what you've done is everything that's currently available to know, read, do, etcetera.

In the case of social sites like Wordpress or Google+, it probably means you've read all the most recent updates that your contacts posted and there's nothing else to read until they post more.

The third definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch%20up) emphasizes "belatedness" as part of the meaning (that is, reading or learning something belatedly), but that depends on usage context.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, hope not offend but in my opinion there seems  be two meanings
a little bit viciously entangled. All in one basket of crabs, 
chattering and learning with and from each other while one is stuck in the records.

Moreover Crab mentality is not far :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_mentality

Let's not confuse: Information is power, whereas  power grab is grab the crab.